# QtQuick - button onClick event

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols

**Background story**

So I recently decided that I should try out Qt. I started making a QtQuick Apllication. In my designer view I have one button and a mouse area.

---

**What I want to do:**

When I click the button, I want to display a message box with some text (like "Hello World").

---

**My Question**

How can I do that ?

---

**Additional info**

I tried googling it, i tried following  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437841/how-to-connect-a-qt-quick-button-click-to-a-c-method)  answer. But still nothing.
I know how to program in .Net (C# and VB), i have some knowage in C/C++, but Qt seems to hard for me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1    

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360

    MessageDialog {
        id: msg
        title: "Title"
        text: "Button pressed"
        onAccepted: visible = false
    }

    Button {
        text: "press me"
        onClicked: msg.visible = true
    }
}
```

And if you prefer to have the dialog dynamically instantiated with arbitrary properties rather than have it "hardcoded", follow the first snippet from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002310/dynamic-instantiation-of-qml-objects/16004056#16004056). You can also set properties in `createQmlObject()` and instead of hiding the dialog just use `destroy()` to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use signals and slots in order to trigger an event. You could use a QMessageBox that pops up to display Hello world.

Comment: Bad idea to mix QtQuick with QWidgets. And unnecessarily tedious. There are already QML message box components.